# React component to return something other than jsx

Tags: javascript, reactjs, redux

I am trying to refactor some code written by someone else and was wondering if the following is possible. can I create a react component that returns non html or jsx? and returns a function or something?

basically the component so far contains 4 functions and then a return block that returns some jsx that gets rendered

I want to extract 2 of these functions out into their own component as they are similar and can be reused

however, these functions just make ajax calls and call other functions rather than returning any jsx. they also require props inside them and need the props either passed in or connected to the redux store
some of the functions it calls are dispatch functions and therefore MUST be connected to the redux store. so I cannot build a standalone function

does this make sense or am I missing something. pseudo code below to demonstrate:

```
const component = ({...props}) => {
   const func1(){
     prop1()
     try{

     } catch(){
      callingAnotherProp()
     }
   }

   const func2(){

   }

   const func3(){

   }

   const func4(){

   }
}
```

imagine `func1` and `func2` were identical. and as you can see they don't return any jsx just make further calls. 
I don't think I can isolate into a sep function. I'd rather not pass the props in as args and just connect the function to the redux store and use the props that way. is this possible?

Comment: So far what I understand is you need HOC ?

Comment: Not very clear what you are trying to do, but you could make a component that calls the functions and just returns null?

Answer (score 0):

What about HOC? You can create a component with the `func1()`method and the `render` function of this component will just return `{this.props.children}`.

The two other options are a standalone function (you don't like it) and inheritance (I don't like it).

Answer (score 0):

Not sure i fully understand your goal here but from what i understand, you want a component that will fetch data and will expose it to other components (or child components?).
There is a nice pattern called [children as a function (or render props)](https://reactjs.org/docs/render-props.html).

Basically you treat the children passed to the component as a function and you can pass the function anything (fetched data in you case).

```
return this.children(this.state.data)
```

Here is a small running example:

```js
class Fetcher extends React.Component {
  state = { result: { data: [] } };

  componentDidMount() {
    const { url } = this.props;
    fetch(url)
      .then(response => response.json())
      .then(data => this.setState({ result: { data } }))
      .catch(err => this.setState({ result: { error: true, message: err } }));
  }

  render() {
    const { children } = this.props;
    return children(this.state.result);
  }
}

class App extends React.Component {
  renderUsers = users => users.map(user => <div>{user.name}</div>);

  render() {
    return (
      <div>
        <Fetcher url={"https://jsonplaceholder.typicode.com/users"}>
          {response => (
            <div>
              {response.data.length
                ? this.renderUsers(response.data)
                : "Loading..."}
            </div>
          )}
        </Fetcher>
      </div>
    );
  }
}

const root = document.getElementById("root");
ReactDOM.render(<App />, root);
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/react/15.1.0/react.min.js"></script>
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/react/15.1.0/react-dom.min.js"></script>
<div id="root"/>
```